# Python error: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a small sample of my dataframe.

```
In [10]: df
 Out[10]:
   TXN_KEY Send_Agent  Pay_Agent  Send_Amount  Pay_Amount
0     13272184  AWD120279  AEU002152        85.99       85.04
1     13272947  ARA030122  AEV000034       402.01      400.00
2     13273453  API185805  API190139        22.98       22.98
3     13273870  ANO080012  API352676       490.00      475.68
4     13274676  AUK359401  AED002782       616.16      600.87
5     13274871  ACL000105  ACB020203       193.78      185.21
6     13275194  ADA374245  ANP023424       100.00       98.50


grouped = df.groupby('Send_Agent')
```

A function to calculate the number of times the Send_Amount is same as the next one works just fine.

```
   def repeat_count(s):
    return (s.shift() == s).sum()

   In [35]: result = grouped.agg({'Send_Amount':[repeat_count]})

   In [36]: result
   Out[36]:
              Send_Amount
              repeat_count
Send_Agent
A03010016             0
A03020026             0
A10000075             0
A10000316             0
A10000932             0
A10060013             0
A10080022             0
A11120030             0
```

But when I am trying to calculate the count of all the Send_Agent where Send_Amount is between 900 and 1000 and I am getting an error:

```
In [27]: def banded_txns(s):
return(s >=900.00 & s  < 1000.00).count()

 In [28]: result = grouped.agg({'Send_Amount':banded_txns})

 TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

I am not able to figure out why it is working for one type of comparison and not for the other. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing some parentheses:

```
def banded_txns(s):
    return ((s >= 900.00) & (s < 1000.00)).count()
```

Comment: @vishal bhatt if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.