# Pandas: creating a new column conditional on substring searches of one column and inverse of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to create a new column in a Pandas data frame based on a substring search of one column and an  inverse of another column.  Here is some data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['ABC-001', 'ABC-002', 'ABC-003', 'ABC-004', 'DEF-123', 'DEF-124', 'DEF-125', 'ABC-987', 'ABC-986', 'ABC-985'],
                   'Color':['04-Red', 'vs Red - 07', 'Red', 'Red--321', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Blue', 'Black', 'Orange'],
                  })


    Manufacturer    Color
0   ABC-001         04-Red
1   ABC-002         vs Red - 07
2   ABC-003         Red
3   ABC-004         Red--321
4   DEF-123         NaN
5   DEF-124         NaN
6   DEF-125         NaN
7   ABC-987         Blue
8   ABC-986         Black
9   ABC-985         Orange
```

I would like to be able to create a new column named `Country` based on the following logic:

a) if the `Manufacturer` column contains the substring 'ABC' and the `Color` column contains the substring 'Red', then write 'United States' to the `Country` column

b) if the `Manufacturer` column contains the substring 'DEF', then write 'Canada to the `Country` column

c) if the `Manufacturer` column contains the substring 'ABC' and the `Color` column does **NOT** contain the substring 'Red', then write 'England' to the `Country` column.

My attempt is as follows:

```
df['Country'] = np.where((df['Manufacturer'].str.contains('ABC')) & (df['Color'].str.contains('Red', na=False)), 'United States',  # the 'a' case
                np.where(df['Manufacturer'].str.contains('DEF', na=False), 'Canada',  # the 'b' case
                np.where((df['Manufacturer'].str.contains('ABC')) & (df[~df['Color'].str.contains('Red', na=False)]), 'England',  # the 'c' case
                         'ERROR')))
```

But, this gets the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

The error message suggests that it might be a matter of operator precedence, as mentioned in:

[pandas comparison raises TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333435/pandas-comparison-raises-typeerror-cannot-compare-a-dtyped-float64-array-with)

[Python error: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252423/python-error-typeerror-cannot-compare-a-dtyped-float64-array-with-a-scalar-o)

I believe I'm using parentheses properly here (although maybe I'm not).

Does anyone see the cause of this error?  (or know of a more elegant want to accomplish this?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to index into `df` here, so just do this:

Just change: `(df[~df['Color'].str.contains('Red', na=False)])`

to: `~df['Color'].str.contains('Red', na=False)`

and it should work.

Also, if you want to break this up for readability and to eliminate some repetition, I would suggest something like this:

```
# define the parameters that define the Country variable in another table
df_countries = pd.DataFrame(
    {'letters': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'ABC'],
     'is_red': [True, False, False],
     'Country': ['United States', 'Canada', 'England']})

# add those identifying parameters to your current table as temporary columns
df['letters'] = df.Manufacturer.str.replace('-.*', '')
df['is_red'] = df.Color.str.contains('Red', na=False)

# merge the tables together and drop the temporary key columns
df = df.merge(df_countries, how='left', on=['letters', 'is_red'])
df = df.drop(columns=['letters', 'is_red'])
```

Or more concise:

```
in_col = lambda col, string: df[col].str.contains(string, na=False)

conds = {'United States': in_col('Manufacturer', 'ABC') & in_col('Color', 'Red'),
         'Canada': in_col('Manufacturer', 'DEF'),
         'England': in_col('Manufacturer', 'ABC') & ~in_col('Color', 'Red')}

df['Country'] = np.select(condlist=conds.values(), choicelist=conds.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way out is use of `np.select(list of conditions, list of choices)`

```
conditions=[(df['Manufacturer'].str.contains('ABC')) & (df['Color'].str.contains('Red')),df['Manufacturer'].str.contains('DEF', na=False),(df['Manufacturer'].str.contains('ABC')) & (~df['Color'].str.contains('Red', na=False))]
choices=['United States','Canada','England']
df['Country']=np.select(conditions,choices)



  Manufacturer        Color        Country
0      ABC-001       04-Red  United States
1      ABC-002  vs Red - 07  United States
2      ABC-003          Red  United States
3      ABC-004     Red--321  United States
4      DEF-123          NaN         Canada
5      DEF-124          NaN         Canada
6      DEF-125          NaN         Canada
7      ABC-987         Blue        England
8      ABC-986        Black        England
9      ABC-985       Orange        England
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy and straightforward way to do it:

```
country = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    if 'DEF' in row['Manufacturer']:
        country.append('Canada')
    elif 'ABC' in row['Manufacturer']:
        if 'Red' in row['Color']:
            country.append('United States')
        else:
            country.append('England')
    else:
        country.append('')
        
df['Country'] = country
```

Of course there will be more efficient ways to go about this w/o looping through the entire dataframe, but in almost all cases this should be sufficient.

Comment: it would be a step backwards to switch from OP's vectorized `np.where` solution to the super-slow `iterrows`